# SQL Server 2000 TOP and OUTPUT keywords

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2000

This query works great in SQL Server 2005 and 2008.  How would I write it in SQL Server 2000?

```
UPDATE TOP 10 myTable
SET myBooleanColumn = 1
OUTPUT inserted.*
```

Is there any way to do it besides running multiple queries?

Comment: I don't think it is possible (never see a way) but it is possible probably as you know with creating a trigger

Comment: Pretty sure you'd have to write a trigger `FOR UPDATE` that does `SELECT * FROM inserted;` - however I haven't tested whether that will behave identically to the above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be honest, your query doesn't really make sense, and I have a hard time understanding your criteria for "great." Sure, it updates 10 rows, and doesn't give an error. But do you really not care which 10 rows it updates? Your current `TOP` without `ORDER BY` suggests that you want SQL Server to decide which rows to update (and that's exactly what it will do).

To accomplish this in SQL Server 2000 (without using a trigger), I think you would want to do something like this:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;

SELECT TOP 10 key_column
INTO #foo
FROM dbo.myTable
ORDER BY some_logical_ordering_clause;

UPDATE dbo.MyTable
SET myBooleanColumn = 1
FROM #foo AS f
WHERE f.key_column = dbo.MyTable.key_column;

SELECT * FROM dbo.MyTable AS t
INNER JOIN #foo AS f
ON t.key_column = f.key_column;
```

If you want a simple query, then you can have this trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.upd_tr_myTable
ON dbo.myTable
FOR UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  SELECT * FROM inserted;
END
GO
```

Note that this trigger can't tell if you're doing your TOP 10 update or something else, so all users will get this resultset when they perform an update. Even if you filter on IF UPDATE(myBooleanColumn), other users may still update that column.

In any case, you'll still want to fix your update statement so that you know which rows you're updating. (You may even consider a `WHERE` clause.)

Comment: Thanks, by great I mean it runs without errors and much quicker than when I try to use SET rowcount.  My query doesn't make sense to you because you don't understand the context I am using it in.  I am going to call this query over and over again until all rows have been selected and updated.  I don't need an order by column as long as the update and select statement pull in the same order.  SQL server can decide.  There are a lot of cases where a programmer may need to pull data in chunks and that is exactly what I am using it for.

Comment: Ok, we'll see you back here when that bites you. The "same order" can change at any time, even between executions of the same query, since if you don't use ORDER BY the engine can consider a *lot* of variables to determine what order would be best.

Comment: Ok thanks, I will do it differently. I am running this query from a .NET application so I will just SELECT the rows into a DataTable object, set the boolean there, then run a batch update from the DataTable object.

Comment: What ordering problem, all the rows will eventually be sent so the order doesn't matter.

Comment: So why do 10 at a time then? And why return all columns, for all 10 rows, to the caller every time?

Comment: Some devices have limited memory, think cell phones. I need all the columns which is why I'm returning all of them.